# post .net core 3 sdk install errors

Tags: c#, .net-core

On Win10, i had .net core 2.2 installed with vs code running fine (using the c# extension). I installed the latest visual studio, thinking it would also install .net core 3, but it didnt, so i downloaded and installed the sdk from:

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/thank-you/dotnet-sdk-3.0.100-windows-x64-installer

Since then when i create a new project (say dotnet new console) I get multiple errors without doing anything:

[image]

running **dotnet --version** returns:

```
dotnet --version
3.0.100
```

**classes.csproj** shows:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

running: **dotnet build**

```
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.3.0+0f4c62fea for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Restore completed in 65.55 ms for E:\training\Csharpe\classes\classes.csproj.
  classes -> E:\training\Csharpe\classes\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.0\classes.dll

    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.95
```

**dotnet restore** returns:

```
  Restore completed in 18.49 ms for E:\training\Csharpe\classes\classes.csproj.
```

if i create a 2.1 app in visual studio i get no issues, so its just v3???

Comment: Add a `global.json` file to force use the 2.2 SDK.

Comment: hi, would that also let it run as v3? looking more for a fix than a work around.

Comment: What does your `classes.csproj` look like? Specifically, what framework does it target? Have you set it to `netcoreapp3.0`?  Have you tried building ? Those could be fake errors caused because VS Code hasn't had a chance to restore the required packages yet.

Comment: hi edited main issue to show outputs.

Comment: Did you install c# extension? https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.csharp.

Comment: yes thats installed. it also tries to do restore when i do a build saying that the

"There are unresolved dependencies. Please execute the restore command to continue."

Answer (score 0):

So finally got this fixed via the following:

Uninstalled .net core 3 
Rebooted 
Installed .net core 3 again (same installed dotnet-sdk-3.0.30.exe)
opened terminal and ran "dotnet --version" which returned v3.
ran "dotnet new mvc"
open in visual code and got no errors !!!

Opened visual studio 2019
Create new project - AND STILL NO .net core 3 option !!!
Updated visual studio from 16.3.1 to 16.3.2  and i have the option to create 3.0 !!!

Thanks
S